# Оформление переноса строки в коде Java

Tags: java

Проблема:

```
System.out.println("1 - Вход" + "2 - Регистрация" + "3 - Меню" + "4 - Поиск" + "5 - Сортировки" + "6 - Сохранение в файл" + "7 - Об авторе" + "8 - О приложении");
```

Есть очень длинная строка, код становится нечитабельным.

Вопрос: Как оформить эту строку с учетом java code conventions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println("1 - Вход" + 
                   "2 - Регистрация" + 
                   "3 - Меню" + 
                   "4 - Поиск" + 
                   "5 - Сортировки" + 
                   "6 - Сохранение в файл" + 
                   "7 - Об авторе" + 
                   "8 - О приложении");
```

Читабельно? - читабельно.

Comment: с учетом java code conventions?

Comment: @studentST, с точки зрения [Oracle Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html#248) и [Google Code Conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.5-line-wrapping) - вполне. В вашей компании могут быть приняты другие правила.

Comment: Правила созданы в первую очередь для чего? Для удобочитаемости разработчиками. Не которые `+` ставят с новой строки. Ну тут на вкус и цвет как говорится